# Append values in one column based on values from another column Python

Tags: python

I have two columns, 'Order_Category' and 'Order_Status', I want to append the 'Order_Category' column to reflect the following:

'F': " - Filled"
'C': " - Cancelled"
'R': " - Rejected"

I need to create a function that will iterate through the 'Order_Status' column and append the 'Order_Category' column when the status equals 'F', 'C', or 'R' and ignore when status equals 'O' or 'X'.

```
def get_status(order_stat):    
    categories = {
            
            'F': [" - Filled"],
            'C': [" - Cancelled"],
            'R': [" - Rejected"],
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could achieve your desired output:

1. Define a function that takes two parameters: one for the order statuses and one for the order categories.
2. Within the function, use a loop or a *vectorized operation* to iterate through the statuses.
3. Check the status and append the corresponding string to the category based on the mapping you provided.
4. Ensure that the function returns the updated list (or series if you're working with pandas) of order categories.

```py
def update_order_category(order_statuses, order_categories):

    # Define the mapping as provided
    status_to_text = {
        'F': " - Filled",
        'C': " - Cancelled",
        'R': " - Rejected",
    }
    
    # Initialize an empty list to hold the updated categories
    updated_categories = []
    
    # Iterate through both lists simultaneously
    for status, category in zip(order_statuses, order_categories):
        # Check if the status has a corresponding update text
        if status in status_to_text:
            # Append the update text to the category
            category += status_to_text[status]

        # Add the updated category to the list
        updated_categories.append(category)
    
    return updated_categories


# Example usage:
order_statuses = ['F', 'C', 'R', 'O', 'X']
order_categories = ['Order1', 'Order2', 'Order3', 'Order4', 'Order5']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order_Category': order_categories, 'Order_Status': order_statuses})


df["Order_Category"] = update_order_category(df['Order_Status'], df['Order_Category'])
df
```

**Output:**

The above solution returns the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

|  | Order_Category | Order_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Order1 - Filled | F |
| 1 | Order2 - Cancelled | C |
| 2 | Order3 - Rejected | R |
| 3 | Order4 | O |
| 4 | Order5 | X |

Comment: this worked, thank you. I had to add a break after 'updated_categories.append(category)'   and the function worked perfectly.